# Render html slider inside chart area

Tags: highcharts

I have a highstock chart. Is it possible to render a slider inside the chart area? There's only simple elements eg text, box etc are given in documentation.

Comment: can you add more details to your question please?

Comment: I need an example of adding a div including some html inside my chart area.

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotations to add some scrollable HTML element:

```
annotations: [{
    labelOptions: {
        ...,
        useHTML: true,
        shape: 'rect',
        formatter: function() {
            return '<div class="annotationContainer"><div>Some text</div></div>'
        },
        y: 15
    }
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sfLum9ep/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/annotations.labelOptions.useHTML

Comment: thanks for your response @ppotaczek. Can we use an input type at the formatter?

Comment: @John  - Yes, we can. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6uevmh10/

Comment: thank you so much. I will implement it and let you know